# 'IntegrityError: column username is not unique' while using Django User model in test

Tags: database, django, testing

While running some tests, I started to get an IntegrityError in my setUp function. Here is my code:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()

    self.emplUser = User.objects.create_user('employee@email.com', 'employee@email.com', 'nothing')
    self.servUser1 = User.objects.create_user('thebestcompany@email.com', 'thebestcompany@email.com', 'nothing')
    self.servUser2 = User.objects.create_user('theothercompany@email.com', 'theothercompany@email.com', 'nothing')
    self.custUser1 = User.objects.create_user('john@email.com', 'john@email.com', 'nothing')
    self.custUser2 = User.objects.create_user('marcus@email.com', 'marcus@email.com', 'nothing')

    ... save users here ...
```

Im wondering as to how this IntegrityError keeps getting raised. I delete all the users in the tearDown function and am using sqlite3 as my DB backend. I see no conflicting usernames and in production, I have no issues with using emails as usernames.

This started happening only half an hour ago, out of the blue. Has anyone run into a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late but more appropriate answer, for the people who would land there after a google search:

When there is interaction with the database in your tests (typically, creating model instances), you should subclass your test class from `django.test.TestCase`, which flushes the database after each test is run.

Then you don't need to write a tedious tearDown method in all your test classes.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#writing-tests

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you're not suffering this problem anymore since you wrote 18 months ago, but I had this problem too, and finally figured out what was happening.  When using Postgres for test cases, DB changes are done in a transaction and simply rolled back, and so it is not necessary to explicitly clear tables in `tearDown()`, however, in SQLite, it is necessary.